# Javascript not working for unknown reason after making some little tiny change to it somewhere

Tags: javascript, html, css

For some reason the javascript code isn't working here. I checked it and javascript code is being executed but it isn't working. The code is at https://codepen.io/EthanID/pen/vXjpqL?editors=0010

Here is the HTML code:

```js
    var cementCount = 10000; //DON'T CHANGE THIS CHEATERS
    var liveCount = 0;
    var clickCount = 0;
    var reset = 0;
    var lay = 0;
    var layCost = 15;
    var mix = 0;
    var mixCost = 5000;
    var roll = 0;
    var rollCost = 10000;
    var belt = 0;
    var beltCost = 250000;
    var form = 0;
    var formCost = 500;
    var mold = 0;
    var moldCost = 1200;
    var set = 0;
    var setCost = 3500;

    document.getElementById("selector").addEventListener("click", addCement);
     //document.getElementById("reset").addEventListener("click", reset);
    document.getElementById("update").addEventListener("click", update);
    document.getElementById("lay").addEventListener("click", buyLay);
    document.getElementById("mix").addEventListener("click", buyMix);
    document.getElementById("roll").addEventListener("click", buyRoll);
    document.getElementById("belt").addEventListener("click", buyBelt);
    document.getElementById("tiny").addEventListener("click", buyTiny);
    document.getElementById("med").addEventListener("click", buyMed);
    document.getElementById("big").addEventListener("click", buyBig);
    document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("click", buyForm);
    document.getElementById("mold").addEventListener("click", buyMold);
    document.getElementById("set").addEventListener("click", buySet);

    function addCement() {
      cementCount = cementCount + 1 + ((form * 10) + (mold * 30) + (set * 100));
      liveCount = liveCount + 1 + ((form * 10) + (mold * 30) + (set * 100));
      clickCount = clickCount + 1;
    }

    function buyLay() {
      if (cementCount > (layCost - 1)) {
        cementCount = cementCount - layCost;
        lay = lay + 1;
      }
    }

    function buyMix() {
      if (cementCount > (mixCost - 1)) {
        cementCount = cementCount - 5000;
        mix = mix + 1;
      }
    }

    function buyRoll() {
      if (cementCount > (rollCost - 1)) {
        cementCount = cementCount - 10000;
        roll = roll + 1;
      }
    }

    function buyBelt() {
      if (cementCount > (beltCost - 1)) {
        cementCount = cementCount - 250000;
        belt = belt + 1;
      }
    }

    function buyTiny() {
      if (cementCount > 499999) {
        var invest = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
        if (invest > 1) {
          var returnType = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
          var returnAmount = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
          if (returnType == 1) {
            lay = lay + returnAmount;
            var returnFinal = " Cement Layers";
          } else if (returnType == 2) {
            mix = mix + returnAmount;
            var returnFinal = " Cement Mixers";
          } else if (returnType == 3) {
            roll = roll + returnAmount;
            var returnFinal = " Steamrollers";
          } else if (returnType == 4) {
            belt = belt + returnAmount;
            var returnFinal = " Conveyer Belts";
          }

          document.getElementById("tinyCount").innerHTML = "<p style='color:green'>This investment has returned " + returnAmount + " " + returnFinal + "</p>";
        } else if (invest == 1) {
          var lossType = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
          var lossAmount = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);

          if (lossType == 1) {
            roll = roll - lossAmount;
            var returnFinal = " Cement Rollers";
            var lossAmountSpecial = lossAmount;
          } else if (lossType == 2) {
            cementCount = cementCount - (lossAmount * 25000);
            var returnFinal = " Cementz";
            var lossAmountSpecial = lossAmount * 25000;
          }
          document.getElementById("tinyCount").innerHTML = "<p style='color:red'>This investment has lost " + lossAmountSpecial + " " + returnFinal + "</p>";
        }
      }
    }

    function buyMed() {
      if (cementCount > 999999) {
        var invest = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
        if (invest > 1) {
          var returnType = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
          var returnAmount = Math.floor((Math.random() * 15) + 1);
          if (returnType == 1) {
            lay = lay + returnAmount;
            var returnFinal = " Cement Layers";
          } else if (returnType == 2) {
            mix = mix + returnAmount;
            var returnFinal = " Cement Mixers";
          } else if (returnType == 3) {
            roll = roll + returnAmount;
            var returnFinal = " Steamrollers";
          } else if (returnType == 4) {
            belt = belt + returnAmount;
            var returnFinal = " Conveyer Belts";
          }

          document.getElementById("medCount").innerHTML = "<p style='color:green'>This investment has returned " + returnAmount + " " + returnFinal + "</p>";
        } else if (invest == 1) {
          var lossType = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
          var lossAmount = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
          if (lossType == 1) {
            roll = roll - lossAmount;
            var returnFinal = " Cement Rollers";
            var lossAmountSpecial = lossAmount;
          } else if (lossType == 2) {
            cementCount = cementCount - (lossAmount * 25000);
            var returnFinal = " Cementz";
            var lossAmountSpecial = lossAmount * 25000;
          }
          document.getElementById("medCount").innerHTML = "<p style='color:red'>This investment has lost " + lossAmountSpecial + " " + returnFinal + "</p>";
        }
      }
    }

    function buyBig() {
      if (cementCount > 4999999) {
        var invest = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
        if (invest > 1) {
          var returnType = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
          var returnAmount = Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1);
          if (returnType == 1) {
            lay = lay + returnAmount;
            var returnFinal = " Cement Layers";
          } else if (returnType == 2) {
            mix = mix + returnAmount;
            var returnFinal = " Cement Mixers";
          } else if (returnType == 3) {
            roll = roll + returnAmount;
            var returnFinal = " Steamrollers";
          } else if (returnType == 4) {
            belt = belt + returnAmount;
            var returnFinal = " Conveyer Belts";
          }

          document.getElementById("bigCount").innerHTML = "<p style='color:green'>This investment has returned " + returnAmount + " " + returnFinal + "</p>";
        } else if (invest == 1) {
          var lossType = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
          var lossAmount = Math.floor((Math.random() * 15) + 1);
          if (lossType == 1) {
            roll = roll - lossAmount;
            var returnFinal = " Cement Rollers";
            var lossAmountSpecial = lossAmount;
          } else if (lossType == 2) {
            cementCount = cementCount - (lossAmount * 25000);
            var returnFinal = " Cementz";
            var lossAmountSpecial = lossAmount * 25000;
          }
          document.getElementById("bigCount").innerHTML = "<p style='color:red'>This investment has lost " + lossAmountSpecial + " " + returnFinal + "</p>";
        }
      }
    }

    function buyForm() {
      if (cementCount > (formCost - 1)) {
        cementCount = cementCount - 500;
        form = form + 1;
      }
    }

    function buyMold() {
      if (cementCount > (moldCost - 1)) {
        cementCount = cementCount - 1200;
        mold = mold + 1;
      }
    }

    function buySet() {
      if (cementCount > (setCost - 1)) {
        cementCount = cementCount - 3500;
        set = set + 1;
      }
    }

    setInterval(updateLay, 1000);
    setInterval(updateMix, 18); //Standard: 20
    setInterval(updateRoll, 8); //Standard: 10
    setInterval(updateBelt, 0.3); //Standard 0.4
    setInterval(updateAll, 10);
    setInterval(updateStock, 10000);

    function updateLay() {
      cementCount = cementCount + (1 * lay);
      liveCount = liveCount + (1 * lay);
    }

    function updateMix() {
      cementCount = cementCount + (1 * mix);
      liveCount = liveCount + (1 * mix);
    }

    function updateRoll() {
      cementCount = cementCount + (1 * roll);
      liveCount = liveCount + (1 * roll);
    }

    function updateBelt() {
      cementCount = cementCount + (1 * belt);
      liveCount = liveCount + (1 * belt);
    }

    function updateAll() {
      document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = cementCount + " Cementz<br>" + ((lay * 1) + (mix * 50) + (roll * 100) + (belt * 2500));
      document.getElementById("layCount").innerHTML = "You Have " + lay + " Cement Layers";
      document.getElementById("lay").innerHTML = "Buy Cement Layer [" + layCost + " Cementz]";
      layCost = Math.floor(100 * (lay * 0.15 + 1));
      document.getElementById("mixCount").innerHTML = "You Have " + mix + " Cement Mixers";
      document.getElementById("mix").innerHTML = "Buy Cement Mixer [" + mixCost + " Cementz]";
      mixCost = Math.floor(5000 * (mix * 0.15 + 1));
      document.getElementById("rollCount").innerHTML = "You Have " + roll + " Steamrollers";
      document.getElementById("roll").innerHTML = "Buy Steamroller [" + rollCost + " Cementz]";
      rollCost = Math.floor(10000 * (roll * 0.15 + 1));
      document.getElementById("beltCount").innerHTML = "You Have " + belt + " Conveyer Belts";
      document.getElementById("belt").innerHTML = "Buy Conveyer Belt [" + beltCost + " Cementz]";
      beltCost = Math.floor(250000 * (belt * 0.15 + 1));
      document.getElementById("formCount").innerHTML = "You Have " + form + " Cement Forms";
      document.getElementById("form").innerHTML = "Buy Cement Form [" + formCost + " Cementz]";
      formCost = Math.floor(500 * (form * 0.15 + 1));
      document.getElementById("moldCount").innerHTML = "You Have " + mold + " Cement Molds";
      document.getElementById("mold").innerHTML = "Buy Cement Mold [" + moldCost + " Cementz]";
      moldCost = Math.floor(1200 * (mold * 0.15 + 1));
      document.getElementById("setCount").innerHTML = "You Have " + set + " Cement Sets";
      document.getElementById("set").innerHTML = "Buy Cement Sets [" + setCost + " Cementz]";
      setCost = Math.floor(3500 * (set * 0.15 + 1));
      achievement();
    }

    function achievement() {
      if (liveCount > 999999) {
        document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "Achievement Get: <div title='You have 1000000 cement bricks!'>The Colin Award</div>";
      } else if (liveCount > 499999) {
        document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "Achievement Get: <div title='You have 500000 cement bricks!'>Lets start investing!</div>";
      } else if (liveCount > 199999) {
        document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "Achievement Get: <div title='You have 200000 cement bricks!'>Your Cement Brick Design Is Envied By Ryan & Gavin</div>";
      } else if (liveCount > 99999) {
        document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "Achievement Get: <div title='You have 100000 cement bricks!'>Your Cement Brick Design Is Envied By Austin</div>";
      } else if (liveCount > 49999) {
        document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "Achievement Get: <div title='You have 50000 cement bricks!'>5 * 10000!</div>";
      } else if (liveCount > 19999) {
        document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "Achievement Get: <div title='You have 20000 cement bricks!'>Let's Get A Warehouse!</div>";
      } else if (liveCount > 14999) {
        document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "Achievement Get: <div title='You have 15000 cement bricks!'>Better Then Brikz</div>";
      } else if (liveCount > 9999) {
        document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "Achievement Get: <div title='You have 10000 cement bricks!'>Let's Get An Office</div>";
      } else if (liveCount > 8999) {
        document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "Achievement Get: <div title='You have 9000 cement bricks!'>Over 9000!</div>";
      } else if (liveCount > 4999) {
        document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "Achievement Get: <div title='You have 5000 cement bricks!'>Small Business</div>";
      } else if (liveCount > 999) {
        document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "Achievement Get: <div title='You have 1000 cement bricks!'>1000 Is Pretty Nice</div>";
      } else if (liveCount > 499) {
        document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "Achievement Get: <div title='You have 500 cement bricks!'>Moving Out Of The Garage</div>";
      } else if (liveCount > 99) {
        document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "Achievement Get: <div title='You have 100 cement bricks!'>One Hundred Is Pro</div>";
      } else if (liveCount > 49) {
        document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "Achievement Get: <div title='You have 50 cement bricks!'>Noob Cementer</div>";
      } else if (liveCount > 0) {
        document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "Achievement Get: <div title='You made your first cement brick!'>Let's Do This</div>";
      }
    }

    function updateStock() {
      var stockTinyType = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
      var stockTinyAmount = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
      var stockMedType = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
      var stockMedAmount = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
      var stockBigType = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
      var stockBigAmount = Math.floor((Math.random() * 25) + 1);
      var string = "";
      var string2 = "";
      var string3 = "";

      if (stockTinyType == 1) {
        string = "<b style='color:red'>^SML -" + stockTinyAmount + "</b>st2st3";
      } else if (stockTinyType > 1) {
        string = "<b style='color:green'>^SML " + stockTinyAmount + "</b>st2st3";
      }

      if (stockMedType == 1) {
        string2 = "<b style='color:red'>^MED -" + stockMedAmount + "</b>";
      } else if (stockMedType > 1) {
        string2 = "<b style='color:green'>^MED " + stockMedAmount + "</b>";
      }

      if (stockBigType == 1) {
        string3 = "<b style='color:red'>^BIG -" + stockTinyAmount + "</b>";
      } else if (stockBigType > 1) {
        string3 = "<b style='color:green'>^BIG " + stockTinyAmount + "</b>";
      }
      var output = string.replace("st2", string2);
      output = output.replace("st3", string3);
      document.getElementById("stock").innerHTML = output;
    }


    document.getElementById("beltCount").addEventListener("click", ee);

    function ee() {
        if (cementCount == 2) {
          cementCount = cementCount + 1000000000000;
          liveCount = liveCount + 1000000000000;
        }
      }
      //(C) Ethan Coe 2016
```

```css
#counter,
#lay,
#layCount,
#mix,
#mixCount,
#roll,
#rollCount,
#belt,
#beltCount,
#tiny,
#tinyCount,
#med,
#medCount,
#form,
#formCount,
#mold,
#moldCount,
#big,
#bigCount,
#stock,
#set,
#setCount {
  text-align: center
}
#shop {
  width: 300px;
  border: 10px solid #696969;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #aeaeae;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
#selector {
  border: 10px solid #696969;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 25px;
}
#counter,
#box {
  text-align: center;
  width: 350px;
  border: 10px solid #696969;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 25px;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 2%;
  right: 2%;
  position: fixed;
}
#counter {
  left: 0;
}
#box {
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#selector {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto
}
body {
  background-image: url("http://www.michaelmolloy.co.uk/construction-photography/photographs/intro/large/construction-site.jpg");
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
body {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}
.change:hover {
  color: white;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.change,
#selector {
  cursor: pointer;
}
/*(C) Ethan Coe 2016*/
```

```html
<img src="http://www.masonrydepotny.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/cocncrete-brick.jpg" alt="Image Missing" height="70" width="70" id="selector">
<div id="shop">
  <p></p>
  <p id="lay" class="change">Buy Cement Layer [100 Cementz]</p>
  <p id="layCount">You Have 0 Cement Layers</p>
  <p id="mix" class="change">Buy Cement Mixer [5000 Cementz]</p>
  <p id="mixCount">You Have 0 Cement Mixers</p>
  <p id="roll" class="change">Buy Steamroller [10000]</p>
  <p id="rollCount">You Have 0 Steamrollers</p>
  <p id="belt" class="change">Buy Conveyer Belt [250000]</p>
  <p id="beltCount">You Have 0 Conveyer Belts</p>
  <hr>
  <p id="tiny" class="change">Buy Small Stock Investment [500000]</p>
  <p id="tinyCount">This Investment Hasn't Been Performed Yet</p>
  <p id="med" class="change">Buy Medium Stock Investment [1000000]</p>
  <p id="medCount">This Investment Hasn't Been Performed Yet</p>
  <p id="big" class="change">Buy Large Stock Investment [5000000]</p>
  <p id="bigCount">This Investment Hasn't Been Performed Yet</p>
  <P id="stock">Generating Stock Market</p>
  <hr>
  <p id="form" class="change">Buy Cement Form [500]</p>
  <p id="formCount">You have 0 Cement Forms</p>
  <p id="mold" class="change">Buy Cement Mold [1200]</p>
  <p id="moldCount">You have 0 Cement Molds</p>
  <p id="set" class="change">Buy Cement Set [3500]</p>
  <p id="setCount">You have 0 Cement Sets</p>
</div>
<div id="counter">0 Cementz
  <br>0 Cementz per Second
  <br>0 Cementz per Click</div>
<p id="box">Welcome to Cementz</p>
<!-(C) Ethan Coe 2016->
```

Comment: That is a lot of code for us to help you with... Can't you narrow it down?

Comment: "Isn't working" doesn't really describe a problem.  Assume that we can't see your screen from here and try to describe the nature of the problem.  If your question it, literally, "My code used to work but I changed something and now it doesn't work" then the answer, clearly, is to undo whatever you broke.

Comment: Lol. We cannot see your tiny change somewhere so perhaps you give us a [mcve] with expected behaviour?

Comment: The console has the error message. Open up the console and you can see the error. Click on it and it takes you to the line....

Comment: Creating a snippet immediately shows you are missing an "update" element in the HTML.  Also we are not allowed to edit your code since it is all _(C) Ethan Coe 2016_ ;) Feel free to delete the question

Comment: Where is your `#update` element??

Comment: Two things: a) As @mplungjan said, please give us a minimal, complete, and verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and b) The relevant code should be **in the question itself**, not just at a link to an off-site resource. Part of the purpose of the Q&A format of this site is to be a resource to other people who have similar problems and not including your code in the question itself interferes with that.

Comment: Ok, second bad question. How do I delete this question?

Comment: To delete this question, try: 1. unaccept (uncheck/untick) the answer. 2. click the "delete" link under the question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

just remove this line:

```
document.getElementById("update").addEventListener("click", update);
```

Or create the update element

Comment: I know this is a badly worded question but thanks for firguring it out.